# How can I host multipal django apps on the same webserver and give each app separate permissions to my postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, apache, webserver, kerberos

How can I host multipal django apps on the same webserver and give each app separate permissions to my postgres database?

I can't figure out a way to do this other than by running multiple instances of apache and having each instance run as a different user that has different permissions to my database. This is very messy and hard to maintain.

I would like to give the apps only the permissions they need.

Any ideas would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'multipal app'?

Comment: This is my go-to tutorial for doing this. Basically you set each Django project up with its own user within the webapps group, give each Django project its own nginx config, gunicorn script, and virtual environment. You manage the starting/stopping of all of them within supervisor:
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: Great tutorial! Thank you!